# Updating multiple bindings silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-4.0, inotifypropertychanged

I have an object that performs multiple calculations whenever any of is input values change.

There are a number of fields bound to the object in xaml. I am currently firing the propertychanged manually for each field however there are a number of properties affected by each update so this is getting tedious and messy.

Is there a way to update everything whenever PropertyChanged is fired regardless of the actual property?

Comment: Do you mean by calling `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null))` once you're done with your calculations to get all bindings bound to the obect to update at once?

Comment: Ok wow - that is exactly what I was looking for. I tried calling it with (null,null) and then gave up on that route. Mind posting that as an answer so I can give you points?

Comment: @Gabe: Add your comment as answer,  @apocalypse9:  using the @name convention in your comments alerts the user to come back and have a look at your comment. (Note only works for the first @name in the comment so that it can't be abused by spammers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null))` once you're done with your calculations, all bindings bound to the obect will be updated at once. By specifying `null` (empty string would also work), you're telling the binding engine "everything changed" so it will refresh all of its bindings against that object.